# Multiple requests on same IdHTTP inside thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, idhttp

I have an application that makes thousands of HTTP requests along the day.
For best performance, I decided to create only once the IdHTTP object and use this same object for all requests. 
This is where the problem begins. While creating one IdHTTP for each request, everything went fine. 
The code is pretty basic:

```
constructor HTTPThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(false);
  httpObject:= TIdHTTP.Create(Nil);
  sslObject:= TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(Nil);
  sslObject.SSLOptions.Method:= sslvTLSv1_2;
  httpObject.IOHandler:= sslObject;
  httpObject.Request.Accept:= frmHTTPRequests.Edit1.Text;
  httpObject.Request.UserAgent:= frmHTTPRequests.Edit3.Text;
  httpObject.ReadTimeout:= 15000;
  httpObject.HandleRedirects:= true;
  FreeOnTerminate:= true;
  OnTerminate:= TerminateProc;
end;


procedure HTTPThread.DoRequests;
var
    htmlSource: string;
begin
    try
      htmlSource:= httpObject.Get(Link);
      //a bunch of other stuff with HTML source
    except
      on E : Exception do
      Synchronize(procedure
      begin
        errorList.Add(E.Message);
        errorList.SaveToFile('Error.txt');
      end);
    end;
end;
```

I created this except saving the Error.txt file to watch what is happening...
The code runs fine sometimes for the first 1k requests, sometimes for the first 2k, it varies. Suddently, it starts writing on the TXT file the same error:

> Connection reset by peer. domain.com - Socket Error # 10054

I tried to disconnect the httpObject, tried httpObject.Request.Clear, nothing seems to work.
Are there any chance to make this work?

Comment: I've had similar issues with TIdHttp and my solution was to re-create the component in case of an error and re-try. Only if the 2nd attempt also failed was it considered an actual problem.

Comment: Have you actually measured how much time and overhead it takes to create the object, compared to doing the actual request? I think the gain is negligible, unless all requests are to the same server, and you could leverage the use of keep-alive connections.

Comment: @GolezTrol I didn't check that... Thank you for the insight.

Comment: @HeartWare ok... Good to know this is a common problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reasons Indy doesn't close socket when server respond with `Connection reset by peer`, so you need to do it manually.

```
procedure HTTPThread.DoRequests;
const
  MAX_TRIES_COUNT = 5;
var
  htmlSource: string;
  TriesCount: Integer;
begin
  TriesCount := 0;
  repeat
    try
      htmlSource:= httpObject.Get(Link);
      //a bunch of other stuff with HTML source
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        if E.Message.Contains('by peer') then
        begin
          httpObject.Disconnect;
          // Try to solve network connection issues
          Continue;
        end
        else
        begin
          // Some other error handlers
        end;
      end;
      inc(TriesCount);
    end;
  until (httpObject.ResponseCode = 200) or (TriesCount > MAX_TRIES_COUNT);
end;
```

P.S. I don't recommend you to use `Synchronize()` for threads synchronization. Try to use [TCriticalSection](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/threadsusingcriticalsections_xml.html) or [TMonitor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.TMonitor) instead.

Comment: "*For some reasons Indy doesn't close socket when server respond with `Connection reset by peer`*" - actually, `TIdHTTP` DOES close the socket on a socket error, and also at the end of each request (whether success or failure) if the server did not agree to use a keep-alive.

Comment: "*`if E.Message.Contains('by peer') then ...`*" - don't do it that way. A better way is to do it like this instead: `if (E is EIdSocketError) and (EIdSocketError(E).LastError = 10054) then ...`, alternatively: `on E: EidSocketError do begin if E.LastError = 10054 then ... end;`. Don't rely on `Message` checks, they are inefficient and prone to localization.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Indy messages are constant, at least for now. I've found this solution long time ago, I don't clearly remember why I've decided to check text message instead of code, but I'm sure that there was a reason for it. I think, you agree that Indy handle this error wrong (and not only this).

Comment: @OlvinRoght "*Indy messages are constant, at least for now*" - Indy's text messages are stored in resource strings and as such are subject to localization by users. "*I think, you agree that Indy handle this error wrong*" - I do not agree with that claim, because it does not match with what `TIdHTTP`'s source code says.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I shouldn't Disconnect it manually when such as error occurred. This should be already done somewhere inside Indy.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Whenever `TIdHTTP` encounters an error while reading an HTTP message, it calls `Disconnect` before raising the error to the user's code. Looking at it again, I don't see it doing the same handling while sending an HTTP message. So I will have to add that. I have [opened a ticket](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/252) in Indy's issue tracker.